# Can't read 'package:intl/intl.dart' only when performing debug build

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart2js

If I 'Pub Build - Minified' my application compiles and runs correctly.  If I instead I do 'Pub Build - Debug' I get the following errors:

```
[Error from Dart2JS on App|web/view_assignment.dart]:
web\code_admin.dart:6:8:
Can't read 'package:intl/intl.dart' (Could not find asset intl|lib/intl.dart.).
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:07.185411 to compile App|web/view_assignment.dart.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling App|web/main.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS on App|web/main.dart]:
web\code_admin.dart:6:8:
Can't read 'package:intl/intl.dart' (Could not find asset intl|lib/intl.dart.).
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Warning from Dart2JS on App|web/main.dart]:
web\index_view.dart:97:7:
Cannot resolve type 'DateFormat'.
      DateFormat acceptUntilFormat = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd H:m');
      ^^^^^^^^^^
[Warning from Dart2JS on App|web/main.dart]:
web\index_view.dart:97:42:
Cannot resolve 'DateFormat'.
      DateFormat acceptUntilFormat = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd H:m');
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:06.744386 to compile App|web/main.dart.
Build failed.
```

My pubspec.yaml has the following entries:

```
name: App
version: 0.0.1
description: An absolute bare-bones web app.
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  bootjack: any
  browser: 0.10.0+1
  intl: any
```

And the folder App/packages/intl exists with a bunch of dart files including intl.dart.  Please advise.

Comment: I have faced same issue, it got resolved after pub cache repair.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that but didn't change the outcome.